# How to prevent repeating data for additional indexes in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I wanted to see how I can add new data when I include a new index into the excel sheet. This is what I mean:

Picture 1 (What my code currently outputs):

[image]

Picture 2 (What I want it to output):

[image]

I want to add `[1, 2]` to row 1, data type 2, and `[3, 4]` to row 2, data type 2. Here's my code for picture 1:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
                    index=['row 1', 'row 2'],
                    columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Add extra index
new_idx = pd.Index(['data type 1', 'data type 2'])
mi1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.index, new_idx])
out1 = df1.reindex(df1.index.repeat(len(new_idx))).set_index(mi1)

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
out1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.close()
```

Is there a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slice(None)` can be used to select all the rows at that level. Since you want to change values where the index is `'data type 2'` in `level=1`, try the following:

```py
# write new values to data type 2 indices
out1.loc[(slice(None), 'data type 2'), :] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

So the full code would look like:

```py
# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], index=['row 1', 'row 2'], columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])

# # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Add extra index
new_idx = pd.Index(['data type 1', 'data type 2'])
mi1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.index, new_idx])
out1 = df1.reindex(df1.index.repeat(len(new_idx))).set_index(mi1)

# write new values to data type 2 indices
out1.loc[(slice(None), 'data type 2'), :] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]    # <-- add this line

# # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
out1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer.close()
```

Then `pd.read_excel('pandas_simple.xlsx', index_col=[0,1])` produces the following frame:

[image: result]

Another way is to change the way you contruct `out1`; instead of reindexing `df1`, construct another dataframe using the same "metadata" as `df1` and concatenate the two:

```py
out1 = (
    pd.concat({
        'data type 1': df1, 
        'data type 2': pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index)
    }).swaplevel().sort_index()
)
```